# Unable to see log (from dart:developer) out in Debug Console of VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I recently got a new MacBook Pro 2021 M1 and setup flutter and VS Code in it. When I run a simple counter app, I want to see the counter value in the Debug Console of VS Code.

**Sample Code**

```
int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    log("_counter -> $_counter");
  }
```

**Problem Faced**

When I run the project, by clicking on **Run Without Debugging** I am unable to see the log in my Debug Console. In all my previous laptops and MacBooks I could see this log output.

**Request**

I would like to know how to resolve the issue and if I am making any mistake here.